# How do I create crossplatform file paths in Go?

Tags: file, io, directory, go

I want to open a given file `"directory/subdirectory/file.txt"` in golang. What is the recommended way to express such a path in an OS agnostic way (ie backslashes in Windows, forward slashes in Mac and Linux)? Something like Python's `os.path` module?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For creating and manipulating OS-specific paths directly use [`os.PathSeparator`](http://golang.org/pkg/os) and the [`path/filepath`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) package.

An alternative method is to always use `'/'` and the [`path`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/) package throughout your program. The `path` package uses `'/'` as path separator irrespective of the OS. Before opening or creating a file, convert the /-separated path into an OS-specific path string by calling [`filepath.FromSlash(path string)`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#FromSlash). Paths returned by the OS can be converted to /-separated paths by calling [`filepath.ToSlash(path string)`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#ToSlash).

Answer (score 53):

Use [`path/filepath`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) instead of [`path`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/). `path` is intended for forward slash-separated paths only (such as those used in URLs), while `path/filepath` manipulates paths across different operating systems.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    path := filepath.Join("home", "hello", "world.txt")
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/2Fpb_vJzvSb

Comment: Must be marked as right answer, quite easier to understand - just use filepath everywhere and... profit!

Comment: Could you add an example?

Answer (score 24):

Based on the answer of @EvanShaw and [this blog](https://golangcode.com/cross-platform-file-paths/) the following code was created:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    p := filepath.FromSlash("path/to/file")
    fmt.Println("Path: " + p)
}
```

On Windows it will return:

```
Path: path\to\file
```

Answer (score -5):

Go treats forward slashes (`/`) as the universal separator across all platforms [[1]](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/5527660c2d860ca3). `"directory/subdirectory/file.txt"` will be opened correctly regardless of the runtime operating system.

Comment: @Atom I don't own a Windows machine. [Russ Cox says Go treats '/' as the path separator on all platforms](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/5527660c2d860ca3), which seems good enough to me.

Comment: Russ made that comment on 2010-01-09. There have been some changes to path handling since then: see http://golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-03-07

Comment: To be perfectly clear, this answer is no longer correct. path/filepath is now always the correct answer to this question.